# Como trocar o link de um video

Tags: html, css

Bom estou com uma certa dificuldade em trocar os links que estão no meu video, montei o player e coloquei os links como normalmente é feito porem montei um painel para a troca de links vamos dizer assim "um modo com interface grafica" mas a partir dai não tenho ideia de como ligar o meu video para esse painel,para a troca/update de link, gostaria de saber como eu conseguiria "linkar" essa pagina a um video, vi que se usa php mas não sei muito sobre, se for isso mesmo, agradeceria se me indicassem um site ou video para mim dar uma estudada sobre.

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge, chrome=1'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
<title>Moderation Control Panel</title>
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="application-name" content="Alpatest">
<meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//www.gstatic.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//api-cdn.embed.ly">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//i.embed.ly">
<link rel="base" href="" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/css/style.crush.css" media="all" />



<h1><i class="material-icons">edit</i> Editar Vídeo
<div class="line linesmall"></div></h1>
<div class="black" id="resultado"></div>
<form action="/mcp/editar-ep?id=96729" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="window.showSnack('Editando...')" data-val="window.showSnack(j.resultado); if(j.id){ $('#resultado').html('<div class=\'p1\'><a href=\''+j.url+'\' target=\'_blank\'>Ir para a página do vídeo</a></div>');  }" method="post" class="frm-api">
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong> Vídeo:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="anime" value="Video" required="required" placeholder="(Nome Exato)">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Tipo:</strong></div><select name="tipo" data-default="Episodio" class="chill col-9 m-12"><option>Episodio</option><option>Filme</option><option>OVA</option><option>Especial</option></select>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Número:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="numero" value="19" required="required" pattern="[^\s]+" placeholder="1 ou 10.5 ou 10-11 (Sem Espaços)">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Audio:</strong></div> <select name="audio" data-default="Legendado" class="chill col-9 m-12"><option>Legendado</option><option>Dublado</option></select>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Imagem/Thumbnail:</strong></div> <input name="img" class="col-9 m-12" type="file" />
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Duração:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="duracao" value="24:25" required="required" placeholder="24:35 (ou 01:23:45)">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-12"><span class="line linesmall"></span></div>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link SD Versão 1:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="sd1" required="required" placeholder="https://servidorprincipal.com.br/sd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link SD Versão 2:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="sd2" placeholder="https://servidor2.com.br/sd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link SD Versão 3:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="sd3" placeholder="https://servidor3.com.br/sd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link SD Versão 4:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="sd4" placeholder="https://servidor4.com.br/sd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link SD Versão 5:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="sd5" placeholder="https://servidor5.com.br/sd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link SD Versão 6:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="sd6" placeholder="https://servidor6.com.br/sd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-12"><span class="line linesmall"></span></div>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link HD Versão 1:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="hd1" placeholder="https://servidorprincipal.com.br/hd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link HD Versão 2:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="hd2" placeholder="https://servidorhd2.com.br/hd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link HD Versão 3:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="hd3" placeholder="https://servidorhd3.com.br/hd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link HD Versão 4:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="hd4" placeholder="https://servidorhd4.com.br/hd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Link FULLHD:</strong></div> <input type="text" class="chill col-9 m-12" name="fullhd" placeholder="https://servidorhd4.com.br/fullhd.mp4 (Link Direto)" value="">
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-12"><span class="line linesmall"></span></div>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Descrição do Vídeo:</strong></div> <textarea name="descri" class="chill col-9 m-12" rows="5">
</textarea>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-12"><span class="line linesmall"></span></div>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Mostrar na inicial</strong></div><select name="mostrar_ini" data-default="1" class="chill col-9 m-12"><option value="1">Sim</option><option value="0">Não</option></select>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Destacar?</strong></div><select name="destaque" data-default="1" class="chill col-9 m-12"><option value="1">Sim</option><option value="0" selected>Não</option></select>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-3 m-12"><strong>Torna-se Autor?</strong></div><select name="autor" class="chill col-9 m-12"><option value="1">Sim</option><option value="0" selected>Não</option></select>
<input type="submit" class="btn green right" value="Editar">
<div class="col-12"></div>
</form> </section>
</div> </div>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito, mas acho que vc precisa salvar as informações num banco de dados e depois puxar pelo PHP (se for usar PHP como backend).

Comment: Essa pergunta não ficou muito clara para mim, você poderia me explicar se é para guardar os links em uma pagina e aplicar em outra, ou se você quer armazenar os links?